# Angular application files upload

Tags: node.js, angular, express

It's a first time I'm doing this so got some trivial (I think) problems with files upload.

I have a pair: Angular 7 app + NodeJS (express) backend. I successfully uploading files (images) through the Angular page, NodeJS save it with correct format, but I don't know what can I do to be able to target just uploaded images in my web-service and where should I store new files. Should it be : src/app/uploads or only src/app ? Can someone explain the idea behind.

Do I need to do any extra actions in Angular? Because it shows me 404 page if I try to target something out of scope of the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that src directory should store only source code (or something change when you update your version of code)
In my opinion, uploaded file shouldnt be stored in src directory.
Maybe

Root dir
- docs
- migrations
- node_modules
- src
- tmp
- uploaded
.......

Comment: and no need to do any other updates and changes? in this case - the path to the file will be: localhost:4000/uploaded/filename.png ?

Comment: no but, if I'm doing like: root/uploaded - I can't access the file from the website.. resource is not found

Comment: You must setup your resources folder and path. Resource can place any where and path can be any string you like
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html